# Why isn't my GridView updating?

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to update the 'question' field when I hit the 'update' button for a specific row. I am able to change the text when I hit the 'edit' button, but when I hit the 'update' button it reverts back to its original value.  Nothing is changed in the database either.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="divGrid" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 70%;">
    <asp:GridView ID="QuestionsGridView" CssClass="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QUESTION_NUMBER" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Question Number" SortExpression="QUESTION_NUMBER" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question" SortExpression="QUESTION" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EditQuestionBox" runat="server" Height="50px" Text='<%# Bind("QUESTION") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="99%" CssClass="multilineTBox" Columns="1" Rows="2"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUESTION") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Width="99%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CAT_NAME" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="CAT_NAME" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QUES_ORDER" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Order in Category" SortExpression="QUES_ORDER" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:CommandField CausesValidation="False" HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="4em" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#a0a0a0" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Corp_TaxConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT tq.id, tq.question, tq.ques_order, tc.cat_name, tq.question_number FROM t01_tax_questions AS tq INNER JOIN t01_tax_categories AS tc ON tq.category = tc.cat_order ORDER BY tq.question_number"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE t01_tax_questions SET question = @question WHERE question_number = @question_number">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="question_number" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="question" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the table:
[SQLServer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCgCY.png)

EDIT:

After looking, in my EditItemTemplate, I bind the question to the textbox.  Is it possible that after I click the update button that the original question is databound to the textbox again before it tries to update?  If this is the case, how would I get around that?

Comment: Not sure if this anything or not (not too familiar with all the sql in the interface like your doing) But it strikes me as odd that your Gridview fields are different case than your sqldata source. Edit: MSDN link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

Comment: Yeah, long story there.  However, changing the case so that they all match doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is this new code? Did you write all this yourself? Or are you supporting an existing application?

Comment: I'm revisiting an old problem from quite a while ago, but yes, I wrote the whole application.  I'm sure some of it was generated when I put the control there, but I don't think that's what your asking @mason.

Comment: My point is that this is using an outdated framework (Web Forms) and not even following the current best practices for that framework. SqlDataSource shouldn't be used anymore (Use an ObjectDataSource backed by a repository pattern that promotes separation of concerns), nor should manually setting styles using attributes be used (that's what CSS is for). Rather than limping along with such an outdated piece of code, you should strongly consider rewriting it to follow modern best practices.

Comment: I completely understand @mason. Like I said, this was written quite a while ago.  Unfortunately, I'm in too deep now to rewrite everything using MVC or do the other things you've mentioned, but I will delete and rewrite the control and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further into it, I realized I had forgotten the apparently very important "DataKeyNames" attribute in my GridView tag.  I feel really dumb.  Here is the new working code.

```
    <div class="divGrid" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 70%;">
    <asp:GridView ID="QuestionsGridView" CssClass="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="ID, QUESTION_NUMBER" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="question_number" HeaderText="Question Number" SortExpression="question_number" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="question" HeaderText="Question" SortExpression="question" >
                <ControlStyle Width="100%" Height="80%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="cat_name" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="cat_name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
                <ControlStyle Height="80%" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ques_order" HeaderText="Question Order" SortExpression="ques_order" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit" ShowEditButton="True" CausesValidation="False" HeaderStyle-Width="4%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" CausesValidation="False" HeaderStyle-Width ="4%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" Width="100%" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#a0a0a0" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Corp_TaxConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT 
        tq.id, tq.question_number, tq.question, tc.cat_name, tq.ques_order
        FROM
        t01_tax_questions AS tq
        INNER JOIN
        t01_tax_categories AS tc
        ON 
        tq.category = tc.cat_order
        ORDER BY tq.question_number"

        DeleteCommand="DELETE
        FROM
        t01_tax_questions
        WHERE
        question_number = @question_number"

        UpdateCommand="UPDATE
        t01_tax_questions
        SET
        question = @question
        WHERE
        id = @id">

        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="@question_number" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="@question"/>
            <asp:Parameter Name="@id" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It is all explained in this [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Thank you to all who looked at this and tried.